# How do I access properties in an array of objects in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How do I use Ruby to access the properties of an object containing an array of objects?

I have a variable that looks something like this:

```
@myvar = [#<MYOBJECT::MObject0x00000000000000="000", @id="1000", 
@status="Open", @color="Red">, #<MYOBJECT::MObject0x00000000000001="001", 
@id="1001", @status="Closed", @blue="450">]
```

I tried:

```
@myvar.each(|name| puts "Status: #{name.status}  Color: #{name.color}"
```

But it returns the full object instead of the property values.

Comment: In this case the problem is not in the code. The OP said he got return values instead of syntax errors. But you are free to decide which version is clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call [`Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each) with a block, it returns the array itself. Perhaps you're looking for [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
array_of_strings = @myvar.map { |name| "Status: #{name.status}  Color: #{name.color}" }
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, [Array#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) returns an array if you supply a block.

If you want an array of "properties", use [Array#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-map). For example,

```
@myvar.map { |obj| obj.status }
#=> ["Open", "Closed", ...]
```

Map creates a new array and replaces each element in `@myvar` with the value 'returned' by the block. Note that this assumes you have a getter method for `status` and other attributes. If you don't, you can create them using `attr_reader :status, ...`.

There is also a more concise version:

```
@myvar.map(&:status)
#=> ["Open", "Closed", ...]
```

(See [The & Operator in Ruby](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/01/04/the-ampersand-operator-in-ruby/).)

Comment: Technically, `Array#each` only returns the array when you supply a block, if you leave out the block, `each` will give you an `Enumerator` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can get instance variable by calling `instance_variable_get("@name")`

```
@myvar.each { |myObject| puts "Status: #{myObject.instance_variable_get("@status")}  Color: #{myObject.instance_variable_get("@color")}" }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is a syntax error in the way you are calling `each` with a paren "(" instead of with curly braces "{". Then there is no corresponding closing paren/brace at the end of the statement. The correct invocation should like -

```
@myvar.each {|name| puts "Status: #{name.status}  Color: #{name.color}"}
```

And this will work only if you have methods `status` and `color` defined in MyObject. If you don't have these methods defined then look at Mike Li's answer to directly access instance variables. This is of course violating OO encapsulation design principle.

Secondly, I noticed that MyObject with id 1001 does not have the `color` attribute, it has an attribute named `blue` with a value of 450.

In order to get a more precise answer to your question, it would help if you could paste in the class definition of MyObject and the exact error that you are getting.